# Loop Through List and Find if String Exists

Tags: java, xml, spring, loops

I have a list that I'm trying to loop through. Essentially I have an XML file with some flights on them. What I'm trying to do is see if what the user searches for is in the XML file, if it is, then display it back to them on a JSP page. What happens is, only the first elements in my XML are stored in the variables. I need to be able to look through the whole XML file and see if the user input exists. For example, based off what I currently have, if I use the `if (startLocation.equals(flight.getStartLocation()) && endLocation.equals(flight.getEndLocation()))`, it will only return Los Angeles, CA for startLocation and Manchester, NH for endLocation. If the user switches what's in the select box, it doesn't work; as I stated, it's only gathering the first flight element.

FlightController.Java

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/submit-search", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public String submitSearch(@RequestParam("name") String name, @RequestParam("startLocation") String startLocation, @RequestParam("endLocation") String endLocation,
            @RequestParam("date") String date, @RequestParam("passengers") Integer passengers, Model model) throws JAXBException, IOException {


        generateFlights();


        File file = ResourceUtils.getFile("classpath:flights.xml");

        try {
            JAXBContext context = JAXBContext.newInstance(FlightList.class);
            Unmarshaller un = context.createUnmarshaller();
            FlightList flightList = (FlightList) un.unmarshal(file);
            List < Flight > list = flightList.getFlights();
            for (Flight flight: list) {

                if (startLocation.equals(flight.getStartLocation()) && endLocation.equals(flight.getEndLocation()))
                {
                    model.addAttribute("startLocation", flight.getStartLocation());
                    model.addAttribute("endLocation", flight.getEndLocation());
                    model.addAttribute("date", flight.getDate());
                    return "ticketInfo";
                }
                else {
                    // Does not exist
                    return "invalidTicket";
                }


            }



        } catch (JAXBException e) {
            model.addAttribute("error", e.toString());
            return "error";
        }

        return null;
}
```

Flight.Java

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlType;

@XmlRootElement(name="flight")
@XmlType(propOrder = { "startLocation", "endLocation", "date" })
public class Flight {
    // Create variables

    String startLocation;
    String endLocation;
    String date;


    // Getters and setters for Flight class

    @XmlElement
    public String getStartLocation() {
        return startLocation;
    }
    public void setStartLocation(String startLocation) {
        this.startLocation = startLocation;
    }
    @XmlElement
    public String getEndLocation() {
        return endLocation;
    }
    public void setEndLocation(String endLocation) {
        this.endLocation = endLocation;
    }
    @XmlElement
    public String getDate() {
        return date;
    }
    public void setDate(String date) {
        this.date = date;
    }


}
```

FlightList.java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessorType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlAccessType;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElement;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlElementWrapper;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
public class FlightList {

    // XmlElement sets the name of the entities
    @XmlElement(name = "flight")
    private List<Flight> flights;


    public void setFlights(List<Flight> flights) {
        this.flights = flights;
    }

    public List<Flight> getFlights() {
        return flights;
    }
}
```

flights.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<flightList>
    <flight>
        <startLocation>Los Angeles, CA</startLocation>
        <endLocation>Manchester, NH</endLocation>
        <date>03-22-2020</date>
    </flight>
    <flight>
        <startLocation>Boston, MA</startLocation>
        <endLocation>Albany, NY</endLocation>
        <date>03-20-2020</date>
    </flight>
</flightList>
```

Comment: `startLocation.equals(flight.getStartLocation()) && endLocation.equals(flight.getEndLocation())` this belongs to the Flight class' domain and should be in this class (maybe as an implementation of `equals` or just as `isSameConnection(Flight other)` or something.

Answer (score 0):

I tried and it works fine for me - I mean parsing.

What you meant by

> What happens is, only the first elements in my XML are stored in the variables.

Here is the code I consider to be working as expected: https://github.com/Betlista/SpringTests/tree/master/FlightsXmlParsing

...as I have in console:

```
b.s.f.SpringBootConsoleApplication       : Los Angeles, CA -> Manchester, NH [03-22-2020]
b.s.f.SpringBootConsoleApplication       : Boston, MA -> Albany, NY [03-20-2020]
```

Comment: When I perform a system.out.println, it will print each individual flight that I have in my XML, but when I'm trying to search for it via a input box, it will only find the first flight, even if the user selects the second flight on the list.